# Python: CSV Parsing and Matching

Tags: python, csv

I would like to match two CSV files and write new CSV file whether those are matching or not.

I mean that if each cell is matching, I would write "1" and if not, I would like to write "0" in new CSV file.

For example,
first file
(14,female,Highschool)

second file
(15,male,Highschool)

I would like to match whether those are same gender or not and same age or not. 
I could write...

```
 f="first_file.csv"
 s="second_file.csv"
 w="writer.csv"
 first = csv.reader(open(f,'rb'))
 second = csv.reader(open(s,'rb'))
 writer = csv.writer(open(w, "w"))
 for row in first:
    for rwo_2 in second:
```

And then I am not sure how I could match....
Please help me.. and thank you in advance..!

Comment: Are you going to match rows in their order? 1st to 1st, 2nd to 2nd, ... ? Do your files have equal row quantity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes you want to match line by line, and pads shorter lines and files with Nones:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

for row1, row2 in izip_longest(first, second, fillvalue=[]):
    writer.writerow([int(a == b) for a, b in izip_longest(row1, row2)])
```

Answer (score 0):

it will not care about repeated rows

```
set(csv1) == set(csv2)
```

else:

```
sorted(csv1) == sorted(csv2)
```